# Tkinter canvas PhotoImage is not appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a problem with my code. I am creating a small video game called Lumanite. I have created the homepage and have started the graphics generation, but I have run into a bug. I am using Python 3.3 and am on a Win 10 laptop. I run the program through a run file, which accesses the main_game file that uses the classes outlined in a separate file, spritesclasses. I am trying to make a sprite appear. Here is the code for the main_game file and the spritesclasses file. (They import the canvas and root from a MENU file)

```
#SPRITES
from tkinter import *
from GUI_FILE import canvas, root
from OPENING_FILE import show, hide

class Sprite():
     def __init__(self, photoplace):
          self.orgin = photoplace
          self.photo = PhotoImage(file=photoplace)
          self.w = self.photo.width()
          self.h = self.photo.height()
     def draw(self):
          self.sprite = canvas.create_image(self.h, self.w, image=self.photo)
```

And the MAIN_GAME file:

```
#Main Game File:
from tkinter import *
from OPENING_FILE import show, hide
from GUI_FILE import root, canvas
from spritesclasses import *


def start_game():
      genterrain()

def genterrain():
       test = Sprite("logo.gif")
       test.draw()
```

And the sprites are not appearing. No error or anything. Please help me. I will supply you with information at a further notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known but tricky issue.  You can read about it in [Why do my Tkinter images not appear?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)  I've implemented one possible solution below:

```
from tkinter import *

class Sprite():
    def __init__(self, photoplace):
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file=photoplace)
        self.w = self.photo.width()
        self.h = self.photo.height()
        self.sprite = None

    def draw(self):
        canvas = Canvas(root, width=self.w, height=self.h)
        canvas.pack()
        self.sprite = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=self.photo)

def start_game():
    genterrain()

def genterrain():
    sprite = Sprite("logo.gif")
    sprite.draw()
    sprites.append(sprite)  # keep a reference!

root = Tk()

sprites = []

start_game()

root.mainloop()
```

The assignment `self.photo = PhotoImage(file=photoplace)` isn't a sufficient reference as the object `test` goes out of scope when `genterrain()` returns and is garbage collected, along with your image.  You can test this by commenting out the line `sprites.append(sprite)` and see your image disappear again.

Also, it wasn't clear why you were positioning the image at it's own width and height -- the first to arguments to `create_image()` are the X and Y position.  I moved canvas creation into `draw()` so I could size the canvas to the image but that's not a requirement of the visibility fix.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really needed that.